# Vega maps highlighting

Tags: topojson, vega

i'm experimenting in enabling Vega graphs/maps on Wikipedia, and looking for a way to draw a map with different countries highlighted with different colors.  So for the map at http://graphtest.wmflabs.org/wiki/Graph:Map I would like to have another table, e.g. US=red,FR=green,HE=blue, etc, which would highlight given countries with colors. Graph's definition uses numeric country IDs, so in reality I will have a table "10":"red", etc. What I can't seem to figure out, is how to mix countries data with highlighting in vega json.

- Feel free to edit that site http://graphtest.wmflabs.org
- Map data is at http://graphtest.wmflabs.org/wiki/Data:Json:World-110m
- Even though filters are enabled at graphtest, they will be disabled at Wikipedia due to security concerns

Answer (score 1):

Your question include 2 issues.

**1. IDs:**

As you pointed out, [the JSON you use](http://graphtest.wmflabs.org/w/index.php?title=Data:Json:World-110m&action=edit), when inspected using http://jsoneditoronline.org , appears to use numbers for IDs, so you currently cannot identify which shape is US, FR, HE. Better to use [this version](http://graphtest.wmflabs.org/wiki/Data:Json:World_named-110m) with `id={country_name_in_english}`. I presently don't have any json under hands with `iso code`, but either English either ISO is necessary for your project. I'am traveling these days. Best and fairely easy would be to get a JSON with both attributes `id={country_name_in_english}, iso={iso_code}`. This is coming soon.

**2. Vega selector:**

I'am not yet familiar with Vega, so I would approach this as a purely D3js issue on how to create, then select the right shapes and color them according to associated data...

```
//Create your D3js shapes with the right attributes
var countries = d3.selectAll(".countries")
   ...  // more d3js code creating the countries' shapes here
   .attr("id", function(d){ return d.id })  // <= important !
   ...

// Custom data
var coloring = [ [ "US", "red"], ["FR", "green"], ["HE", "blue"] ];

// Color the given shapes
for (i=0; i < color.length; i++) {
    var focus = d3.selectAll("#"+coloring[i][0])
                .style("fill", coloring[i][1]);
}
```

**Note:** A purely Vega solution for this would be more elegant for sure.

Comment: @yurik: Happy to eventually meet you, I work on the Wikimedia WikiAtlas IEG which will provide your nice topojsons and d3js codes. Please follow [wikiatlas](http://twitter.com/wikiatlas) on twitter and tweet me. :)

Comment: Hi @hugopolz! Unfortunately I can't use non-Vega approaches here, as users won't have access to JavaScript (hence the reason to use Vega in the first place). I am aware of the first issue, but I think I can tackle it with a re-coding module I already built using Lua, so it won't be as critical to solve at this stage. After reading a bit more on Vega, I think I will need to do some sort of data transformation before using it to draw shapes, TBD. Would love to meet, I'm in NY but bounce around a lot.

Comment: Ok, cool to learn you see Vega possibilities (which I don't clearly see yet). We need to be able to provide specific [specific WP styles](https://rugger-demast.codio.io/front/_location_map-en-SO.html) and new interactive behavior. Out of embedding of dynamic viz into mediawiki (already critical!), I haven't myself a clear view of Vega's possibilities. I'am in Paris and going twice a year to Wikimedia events : Wikimania, Hackathon. For issue 1, It's just a custom export from shapefile into topojson. No need to code any module.

Comment: The main benefit of vega - an ability to describe a graph WITHOUT javascript. We can't allow javascript to be editable by anyone on the site due to security and privacy concerns. Vega is a good conversion from json to javascript calls, descriptive enough to fit the bill, and with some tweaks should be secure enough for this purpose. And yes, I really want the dynamic stuff at some point... somehow :)

Comment: Vega Interactive are now live on Wikipedia -- https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Graph/Demo#Vega_2.0_Interactive_Examples